# How to detect drag and move left mouse down in a modal operator?

Tags: python

I would like to be able drag and move mouse to adjust some parameter inside a modal operator. I can detect mouse clicks, or a release but I have not been able to find a way to do `mouse press down` and `drag`  to increase or decrease values.

Basically I would like to be able to press a key and drag  mouse to change some values. For instance I press down `f` and start dragging mouse to change a value.

Any recommendations?

thanks

Comment: Maybe use a flag variable to save the pressed state?